# React.js state confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still trying to understand the state concept in react.js. Can anyone please help with the below jsfiddle? I am trying to filter the records based on the category selected.

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
        <div>
            <Instructions />
            <h1>Requests</h1>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Include your instructions component in the code so we can see please.

Comment: Please remove it, instructions was just a place holder

Comment: You've given us no code to look at apart from a fiddle...?

Comment: I dont want to copy the same code in the question coz thats all the code I am working with.

Comment: Aside from having a question that doesn't show much aside from a link (usually a bad idea since links aren't forever) Your code is broken in multiple places. 

1. you are calling a function that doesn't exist.
2. you are doing an assignment instead of comparison (i.e. = instead of ==)
3. you aren't doing anything with your newData after looping over it.
4. you aren't using the text value but the numeric value so your comparison is bad anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've found with react, communicating changes between components that don't have a parent-child relationship kind of requires the state to be managed in a top-level component that is a parent to both the components that are trying to communicate. In your example, `App` is your top-level component that contains `MySelect` and `DisplayRecords` as children. If you want the status of `MySelect` to affect the rows shown in `DisplayRecords`, you'll have to manage that in the state of `App`.

In the example, I moved the select box' selection to the state of `App`, and passed props to the different components accordingly. I tried my best to explain the notable changes with comments, but if you have questions about any changes, definitely leave a comment!

```
var DisplayRecords = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var _this = this; // avoid conflicting this keyword
    return (
        <div>
        <table><tbody> // include tbody to avoid errors (weird react thing)
         {_this.props.records.map(function(record){ // loop through each record
            // if all records is selected, or the record status matches the selection
            if(_this.props.filter=="All Requests" || record.status == _this.props.filter){
              // return the record as a table row
              return (
                <tr key={record.id} >
                <td>{record.title}</td>
                <td><a href="#">{record.status}</a></td>
                <td>{record.updated_at}</td>
                <td>{record.created_at}</td>
                <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
              )
            }
          })}
        </tbody></table>
     </div>
    )
  }
});

var MySelect = React.createClass({
  callParentFunction: function(e) {
    // call parent's getFilter function with the selected option's text as argument
    this.props.changeHandler(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
  },
  render: function() {
    // note removed specified value of select box
    return (
      React.createElement("select", { onChange: this.callParentFunction},
         React.createElement("option", { value: 1 }, "All Requests"),
         React.createElement("option", { value: 2 }, "Approved"),
         React.createElement("option", { value: 3 }, "Denied"),
      React.createElement("option", { value: 4 }, "Pending")
      )
    )
  }
});


var App = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    // set initial selection
    return {
     selected: "All Requests"
    }
  },
  getFilter:function(newFilter){
    // set new selection on change of select box
    this.setState({selected: newFilter})
  },
  render: function() {
    // pass selected state to both MySelect and DisplayRecords
    // pass getFilter to MySelect so it can be called onChange
    return (
      <div>
        <MySelect selection={this.state.selected} changeHandler={this.getFilter} />
        <h1>Requests</h1>
          <DisplayRecords records={this.props.data} filter={this.state.selected} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.render(<App data={requests}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have multiple states?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple states? The state will change over time depending on the interaction from the user.